# How to change the default directory docker uses to build an image

Tags: linux, docker, gitlab, docker-build, podman

I am trying to set up a gitlab ci.

Because I for some reasons I do not have "gitlab-runner" user and I do not have permission writin on "/home/user_1", this is my installation

```
/usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner install --user=user_1 --working-directory=/data/external/tmp/gitlab-runner
```

And this is how I register

```
/usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner register --url GITLAB_URL --registration-token TOKEN
```

By the way, I create this gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  # only:
  #  - 3.0.x
  script:
    - echo "deploying"
    - sudo docker build -t my_image:v1 .
    - echo "********Docker Images********"
    - sudo docker image list
    - echo "********End of Docker Images********"
    - sudo docker run -d -p 3000:5000 --rm --name my_container my_image:v1

  tags:
    - deploy
```

I get this error:

```
Error: error creating build container: Error committing the finished image:

error adding layer with blob "sha256:bb7d5a84853b217ac05783963f12b034243070c1c9c8d2e60ada47444f3cce04": 

Error processing tar file(exit status 1): 

Error setting up pivot dir: mkdir 

/home/user_1/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/62a747bf1719d2d37fff5670ed40de6900a95743172de1b4434cb019b56f30b4/diff/.pivot_root436648414: 

permission denied
```

I would like to replace `/home/user_1/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/`
with another address so that I do not get permission error.

Any advice on how to do so?

I am using Redhat Linux
docker --version is podman version 3.2.3

docker info:

```
server_name:/home/my_user[ 52 ] --> docker info
host:
  arch: amd64
  buildahVersion: 1.21.3
  cgroupControllers: []
  cgroupManager: cgroupfs
  cgroupVersion: v1
  conmon:
    package: conmon-2.0.29-1.module+el8.4.0+11822+6cc1e7d7.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 2.0.29, commit: ae467a0c8001179d4d0adf4ada381108a893d7ec'
  cpus: 8
  distribution:
    distribution: '"rhel"'
    version: "8.4"
  eventLogger: file
  hostname: server_name
  idMappings:
    gidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 1000
      size: 1
    uidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 67298
      size: 1
  kernel: 4.18.0-305.3.1.el8_4.x86_64
  linkmode: dynamic
  memFree: 1818484736
  memTotal: 33444728832
  ociRuntime:
    name: runc
    package: runc-1.0.0-74.rc95.module+el8.4.0+11822+6cc1e7d7.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/runc
    version: |-
      runc version spec: 1.0.2-dev
      go: go1.15.13
      libseccomp: 2.5.1
  os: linux
  remoteSocket:
    path: /run/user/67298/podman/podman.sock
  security:
    apparmorEnabled: false
    capabilities: CAP_NET_RAW,CAP_CHOWN,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE,CAP_FOWNER,CAP_FSETID,CAP_KILL,CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE,CAP_SETFCAP,CAP_SETGID,CAP_SETPCAP,CAP_SETUID,CAP_SYS_CHROOT
    rootless: true
    seccompEnabled: true
    seccompProfilePath: /usr/share/containers/seccomp.json
    selinuxEnabled: false
  serviceIsRemote: false
  slirp4netns:
    executable: /bin/slirp4netns
    package: slirp4netns-1.1.8-1.module+el8.4.0+11822+6cc1e7d7.x86_64
    version: |-
      slirp4netns version 1.1.8
      commit: d361001f495417b880f20329121e3aa431a8f90f
      libslirp: 4.3.1
      SLIRP_CONFIG_VERSION_MAX: 3
      libseccomp: 2.5.1
  swapFree: 67353165824
  swapTotal: 67448598528
  uptime: 789h 40m 40.57s (Approximately 32.88 days)
registries:
  localhost:
    Blocked: false
    Insecure: true
    Location: localhost
    MirrorByDigestOnly: false
    Mirrors: []
    Prefix: localhost
  mkdcvtmaapp01:
    Blocked: false
    Insecure: true
    Location: server_name
    MirrorByDigestOnly: false
    Mirrors: []
    Prefix: server_name
  search:
  - registry.access.redhat.com
  - registry.redhat.io
  - docker.io
store:
  configFile: /home/my_user/.config/containers/storage.conf
  containerStore:
    number: 0
    paused: 0
    running: 0
    stopped: 0
  graphDriverName: overlay
  graphOptions:
    overlay.mount_program:
      Executable: /bin/fuse-overlayfs
      Package: fuse-overlayfs-1.6-1.module+el8.4.0+11822+6cc1e7d7.x86_64
      Version: |-
        fusermount3 version: 3.2.1
        fuse-overlayfs: version 1.6
        FUSE library version 3.2.1
        using FUSE kernel interface version 7.26
  graphRoot: /home/my_user/.local/share/containers/storage
  graphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: nfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "false"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Using metacopy: "false"
  imageStore:
    number: 0
  runRoot: /run/user/67298/containers
  volumePath: /home/my_user/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes
version:
  APIVersion: 3.2.3
  Built: 1627570963
  BuiltTime: Thu Jul 29 11:02:43 2021
  GitCommit: ""
  GoVersion: go1.15.7
  OsArch: linux/amd64
  Version: 3.2.3
```

I also have tried these three in my gitlab ci but it did not work:

```
deploy:
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TMP: /data/external/tmp_docker_build
    TMPDIR: /data/external/tmp_docker_build
```

I also did `chmod 777` on `.local`, `share`, `containers`, `storage`, and overlay in this rout `/home/user_1/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/` but it is still not working.

Comment: Try setting the environment variable `DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2` or configuring it in your runner's docker daemon.

Comment: What operating system are you using and can you include the output of `docker info` ?

Comment: @sytech
I am using RedhatLinux. I included docker info to the end of the question. Thank you

Comment: @sytech
About `DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2`, I added the result to the end of the question

Comment: this is just a guess: what is in `seccompProfilePath: /usr/share/containers/seccomp.json` does this file permit writing to a user home?

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann
How should I understand it from this file? It is a big json file? Which key?

Comment: Sorry, on my Ubuntu there is no such file. Can you post it in a pastebin somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I did not know about this before, either. Apparently you can set the data dir used by docker daemon by adding `-g /path/to/dir` to the docker daemon command.

For example by adding `-g` to the `DOCKER_OPTS` in `/etc/default/docker` on Ubuntu or Debian systems:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-dns 8.8.8.8 -dns 8.8.4.4 -g /data/external/docker"
```

My source is https://forums.docker.com/t/how-do-i-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory/1169 - there is also a note about how this is done on Fedora or CentOS:

> edit `/etc/sysconfig/docker`, and add the `-g` option in the `other_args` variable: ex. `other_args="-g /var/lib/testdir"`. If there’s more than one option, make sure you enclose them in `" "`. After a restart, (`service docker restart`) Docker should use the new directory.

Comment: I prefer not to change the settings of the Docker on the system.
So, based on your solution, what should be this line of code my gitlab-ci.yml file
`sudo docker build -t my_image:v1 .`
And my system is redhat linux

Comment: No, changing the docker client command will not change where docker daemon writes stuff as the client only tells the daemon what to do, but has no influence on where the daemon does it.

Comment: I do not have `/etc/sysconfig/docker` in my system